# Solder Phenomenon

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

I recently saw an interesting phenomenon. I was soldering a piece of electronics and once I was at the end of my wire I could simply let go and the (small) solid piece of wire would be sucked in to the molten solder blob.

[image]

I am curios what causes this force. Perhaps it is pressure difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect this is a result of [surface tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension).

Comment: I am not to familiar with this concept. The break in the surface causes this? Could you elaborate.

Comment: surface tension?that means capillary action I guess.

Comment: @AmritanshSinghal: Ruslan kindly added a link.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to surface tension. This effect is exploited in reflow soldering of surface-mount (SMT) devices on printed circuit boards (PCBs)

- [Example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5lksMvmqQc), look at R2 at 0:13
- [Example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8fiiCTRHW8)
- [Discussion of undesirable effects](http://www.circuitnet.com/experts/86914.html)
- [University of Bristol](http://www.bristol-seds.co.uk/soldering/reflow/2014/09/06/pico-reflow.html)

> Don’t worry if the components aren’t prefectly aligned at this stage: When you reflow the surface tension of the molten solder will pull them into place.